# Horizontal paging UICollectionView with automatic item size in a vertical stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, ios12

I have a main vertical stack view (Frame 1), that has a horizontal paging collection view with flow layout (CollectionView), which has a couple of cells (Cell). Each cell comes with a vertical stack view of a couple of labels (Title, Description).

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to let the tallest cell determine the collection view's height, while the main stack view width determines the width of the cells?

---

By default, the collection view is not visible when I use `layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize` (seemingly it does not "inherit" the cells' height).

For now, **I worked around the issue by setting a fixed height** for the collection view, and defined the item size manually in the `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` (and the cells are flexible).

Comment: Are you trying to have your cells's content define the height of the collection view? Your cells have a *"stack view of a couple of labels"* ... do you mean a *vertical* stack view? Are all the cells the same height? Or do you want your horizontal collection view cells to have differing heights?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for getting back! Yep, optimally the tallest cell should define the height of the collection view. And yeah, the stack views with the labels are vertical (I'll update the question, too).

Comment: How many cells will you have? Just a "few"? Or possibly "many"?

Comment: @DogMag Added a quick sketch that resembles what I'm about to do. For my current use-case, there is only 3 cell (with static content), yet I'm looking for a scalable approach.

Comment: @DonMag I clarified the question, perhaps it helps with answering.

Comment: Hmm... ...as I started to think, the rightmost cell is not even instantiated/initialized at the beginning. Perhaps using a `UIScrollView` is the best for static cell content with auto-size requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since CollectionViews (and TableViews) don't have an `intrinsicContentSize`, there is no way for the layout engine to know the correct size of your collection without the appropriate constraints. A subclass is needed to provide this property.

In your subclass:

```swift
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(self.contentSize.height, self.superview!.bounds.width)
}
```

Also, don't forget to invalidate your content size when reloading data:

```swift
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

For a more detailed explanation on intrinsicContentSize check Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize)

Answer (score 0):

As the content is static, I think **simply using `UIScrollView`** is a pretty viable alternative here (as the dynamic nature of the collection view is not a requirement). The collection view could be a stack embedded into a scroll view, then the contains between the dimensions can be simply set upon initialization.