# Match collection view height to height of cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

I have a collection view subclass within a vertical stack view that I want to resize its height to fit one row of my cells perfectly inside it.

I've tried many solutions on StackOverflow already including using contentSize and collectionViewContentSize which are both 0 unless I give the collectionView a constant height or a size relative to its superview (which then the contentSize is just equal to that of the constant which could be too tall or too small) but if the height is too smalls the cells are cut off at the bottom. I don't want to use static heights as I want the collection view height to be dynamic based on the rotation and size of the screen.

I've seen a few posts about making a new flow layout but seeing as the current flow layout works just fine for displaying my cells do I really need to make a whole new subclass?

Not really sure what code I would post here, the collection view cells themselves have another vertical stack view (which fills up the entire view) that contains 3 labels and an image view (which as a 16:9 constraint on it and it cannot be more than 250 px in width). Let me know if any information would be helpful in solving this.

Comment: Have you looked at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598968/horizontal-paging-uicollectionview-with-automatic-item-size-in-a-vertical-stack ? That collection view is in a stack view, but that doesn't matter... it's still "how to set the height of a collection view based on its cells"

Comment: Yes, I have. The problem with setting the intrinsic content size to the content size height is that the contentSize height is always 0 as I stated in my question.

Comment: It's not clear, then, what you really want to do. Your question states that you want the collection view to both *"size its height based on the cell height"* but also *"change its height based on rotation and size of the screen"*. Are you cells different heights? Do you want the collection view (and related UI elements) to change height/position with every cell that is scrolled into view? Are you trying to figure out how to make the collection view height equal to the tallest possible cell?